# Check send/receive error message in taskbar in outlook

Tags: vb.net, vba, outlook

Following link shows send/receive error message in taskbar.
http://www.stellaroutlooktools.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/send-receive-error.jpg

I am looking for a vb.net code like following;

```
If Outlook.Taskbar.Message.Text = "Send/Receive error" Then
    Msgbox "Error in outlook"
End If
```

or;

```
If Outlook.HasError = True Then
    Msgbox "Error in outlook"
End If
```

Comment: So what is your question? Are you trying to find out if the latest Send/Receive failed?

Comment: If outlook has error then I will tell my program that dont start running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SyncObject.SyncStart/SyncEnd/OnError` events. 
Retrieve SyncObject from the Application.Session.SyncObjects collection. The very first item will be "All Accounts" sync object.

Comment: You are perfect! Thank you very much. Have a nice day.